# Forgot to add a user to local user accounts before running Sysprep-generelize with Unattend XML file on Win10 pro machine

Tags: windows, user-accounts, sysprep

I forgot to add a user to the local user accounts before running Sysprep-generelize with Unattended XML file on Win10 pro machine an
I'm locked out
The Admin user became unavailable and there are no users in the system.
Is there a way to add a user "outside" the image?
What else is possible before reformatting the image ?

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account using WinRE, or reapply the image, after you create a local Administrator account.

Comment: Are you trying to create an image for ongoing repeat use? If so, you should recreate it. If you're just trying to fix a one off, then the linked guide should be fine.

Comment: I was trying to modify the reg key F via WinRE , but it already seemed to be modified to enable admin account (value 10) , so eventually I used one of Hirens 10 App's to enable the admin account and I was able to log in successfully ,ran sysprep and recaptured the image .